# Sharepoint 2013 out of the box workflow Approval Help

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

I am really in need of help. Actually, I have out of the box workflows which crashed at certain levels. The issues are as following.

- Task is assigned to User and status is "In Progress". User is approving the task bu status is not changing.
- Some workflows were in the middle and started showing status "Error Occurred".

Is there any way to resolve without cancelling the workflow and fix it using powershell script or some technique to make it working from its last point. Even I dont have any other option then how can maintain its history when cancel the workflow and reassign after adding the remaining approvers but having all the history. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As you are using out of the box wf I don't think this is possible. You will have to start from the beginning. In custom WF on project we cater for that situation where we could set the WF stage if we had to stop it. We were using WF 2013 which proven to be very faulty WF engine (Workflow Manager)

Comment: Marek Thanks. But I think definitely there should be a way by setting few values using using powershell script or by SharePoint Client object model. However, we are not aware.